# What is the difference between static and protected in java?

Tags: java

hello I am currently studying for a programming exam in java and I would like to understand the difference between a static method and a protected one. thanks in advance

Comment: Please use google search or stackoverflow search before posting a question.

Answer (score 3):

Those two are different concepts.

[`static` defines whether a field or method belongs to the class or its instances](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

[`protected` influences the visibility of a field or method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html). When a field or method is set to `protected` visibility, only classes inheriting from this class can access the field or method.

Notice that those two keywords are orthogonal: a field or method could be decorated with `static` and `protected` simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Static classes and protected classes can coexist for a single variable, so they are very different things. If you don't have a good grasp on Object Oriented programming, I highly recommend finding tutorials on YouTube, as there are some really good ones! :)

**Static Variables**
Are variables that belong to the *class*, not each individual object that the class creates. This means that if the variables is changed, it changes for everything.

**Protected Variables**
Are variables that are only accessible to it's child classes. A child class will have the variable, but no other classes will have access to it. If you know the difference between public variables and private variables, protected is kind of like a middle ground.

This is a tutorial series I recommend to learn more. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLAF3anQEEkzQPQv3FAhIuSWrepTayQJpL

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem a newbie to java language, in a nutshell:

***protected***: An Access modifier(member variables + methods). You can find a whole lot of explanation over the internet.

***static***: NOT-An-Access modifier(blocks, variables,methods, nested classes)

You might want to check SIB/IIB (static and instance Initialization Blocks for a clear concept of static)

Comment: yeah i'm still quite new to java , thanks for the info :)